# how to convert comma seperated values to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas.

```
  order_id    no
  1           1,234,450,445.00 
  2           1,234,450,446.00
  3           1,234,450,447.00
```

I want to convert the no column to integer. Following is my desired dataframe.

```
  order_id    no
  1           1234450445 
  2           1234450446
  3           1234450447
```

When I do dtypes, it shows as `float64`

I tried following

```
df['no'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['no'].str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce'))
```

How can I convert this to integer in pandas?

Comment: Try ``df.no.str.replace(",", "").str[:-3].astype(int)``. If you are reading in the file as a csv, pandas has a [thousands](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#thousand-separators) parameter

Comment: @sammywemmy It gives me following error. `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
`

Comment: what do you get when you use just ``df.no.str.replace(",", "").str[:-3]``?

Comment: @sammywemmy Same error

Comment: @Neil try this, ``df.no.str.replace(",", "").astype(float).astype(int)``

Comment: what is the dtype for the column? it should be a string column right?

Comment: @sammywemmy dtype of the column is `float64`

Comment: seems one of the answers below worked for you. cheers

Comment: Where does the original dataframe come from? It may be cheaper to fix the problem at the reading stage by providing the `thousands=','` option to the CSV reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way, go through float type first:

```
df['no'].str.replace(',','').astype(float).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    1234450445
1    1234450446
2    1234450447
Name: no, dtype: int64
```

Or slice '.00' off then end of all rows:

```
df['no'].str.strip('.00').str.replace(',','').astype(int)
```

Comment: it is still giving me `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` this error. Moreover `no` column is already in `float64` format

Comment: When I try to convert it to string `df['no'] = df['no'].astype(str)` it gives same error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
`

Comment: @Neil Can you do this on the first five rows is it  successful?  You need to find the errant data.  If so, try the next few rows until you find a rows that is causing the problem.   Post that to this question if you are unsure how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Hope can help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['no'] = df['no'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: "".join(x.split(","))).astype(np.float64).astype(np.int64)
```

or

```
df['new_no'] = df['no'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: int(float("".join(x.split(",")))))
```